# iptables command , iptables: No chain/target/match by that name

Tags: iptables, debian-stretch

So I'm trying to install and test out Github loadbalancer.For this I need to configure the proxy servers behind the loadbalancer.
One of the last steps involved in configuring it is to configure iptables:

```
sudo iptables -t raw -A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 19523 -j CT --notrack
```

I get the following error:

> iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.

All of it only works on debian so I am presently installing and configuring everything on docker containers.Is there a problem at the docker container level, or a problem with the packages installed to use the loadbalancer i.e to configure the proxy server.

https://github.com/github/glb-director/blob/master/docs/setup/backend-proxy-setup.md

https://github.com/github/glb-director/blob/master/docs/setup/packages-quick-start.md

I read a similar post here and realized that a part of the command goes through without throwing up any errors. This part is:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 19523
```

Comment: I always thought that the INPUT chain was in the nat table not the raw table https://stuffphilwrites.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/FW-IDS-iptables-Flowchart-v2018-11-14.png

Comment: Are you running this command inside a container, or on the container host?

Comment: @MichaelHampton yes,I'm using the command inside the docker container

Comment: @sddsfds Hmmm...Yes,I see your point,using -A PREROUTING instead works.

Comment: One more question,what would be the effect of the following commands:        
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 19523                                                sudo iptables -t raw -A PREROUTING -p udp -m udp --dport 19523 -j CT --notrack